# When jQuery Adds Fixed Class To Bootstrap Navbar Page Jumps

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I noticed an issue with one of my pages and I finally tracked down the issue. On my page I have a header then my navbar sits below it. Once the navbar is off screen jQuery adds a `fixed-top` class to that it scrolls with the page. On one of my pages where there isn't a lot of content there was some jumping when I scrolled to the bottom. I realized that this was because when the `fixed-top` class was added the page no longer needed the scrollbar thus resulting in the jQuery removing the `fixed-top` class resulting in a cycle that made the page appear to jump.

This is my jQuery for the navbar.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var topofDiv = $(".top-header").offset().top; //gets offset of header
  var height = $(".top-header").outerHeight(); //gets height of header
  console.log($(window).scrollTop());
  if($(window).scrollTop() > (topofDiv + height)){
    $('.nav-top').addClass('fixed-top');
  } else {
    $('.nav-top').removeClass('fixed-top');
  }
});
```

One thing that I tried was when the class was added add to the height of the header to make up for the loss of the navbar but that didn't seem to work either. Mostly because it kept adding the height over and over resulting in a very large header. Here is that function:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var topofDiv = $(".top-header").offset().top; //gets offset of header
  var height = $(".top-header").outerHeight(); //gets height of header
  console.log($(window).scrollTop());
  if($(window).scrollTop() > (topofDiv + height)){
    $('.nav-top').addClass('fixed-top');
    $('.top-header').height(function (index, height) {
      return (height + 60);
    });
  } else {
    $('.nav-top').removeClass('fixed-top');
  }
});
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like you are on the right track, but you should be accounting for that removed space *taken out of the document flow* by applying the header height to the body or any containing element of the header and page.

Comment: You should add a `padding-top` for the body that equals the header's height when the nav is removed.